# Undefined method? Controller params in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the weirdest error I have ever seen, consider the following create method:

```
  def create
   post = Post.find_by(id: params[:post_id])
   @comment = Comment.new(comment_create_params)
   @comment.post_id = post.id #I know this line is useless I have yet to refactor.
   controller_save(@comment)
  end
```

From here we have `comment_create params` which is a private method but is defined as such:

```
  def comment_create_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:author, :comment, :parent_id)
  end
```

Now consider the following `params` that were passed in:

```
params => {"author"=>"157685iyutrewe1wq",
 "comment"=>"14253647turyerwe",
 "action"=>"create",
 "controller"=>"api/v1/comments",
 "post_id"=>"126"}
```

Based on this everything looks correct. Running through this function everything should save. Till I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `permit' for "14253647turyerwe":String
```

I have no idea what this means - I think its trying to treat: `"14253647turyerwe"` as a method which is a string? not sure....

Comment: Can you add your comment form please?

Comment: My comment form is rendered in reactjs and the data is passed back through json. @JKen13579

Comment: What are the attributes of your `Comment` model? Currently this is wrong `params.require(:comment).permit(:author, :comment, :parent_id)`.You are permitting `comment` as an `attribute` which is a `model instance`

Comment: crap they are `comment` and `author` ..... I didn't think this would be an issue. So I have to change comment (model attribute) to something, other then comment is what I am guessing. Because its conflicting with the model name @Pavan

Comment: It is not a good idea to have attributes that share the same name as the model.

Comment: You should be permitting your related attributes in there.What are the attributes of your Comment model?

Comment: @Pavan I already told you, `author` and `comment`

Comment: @enragedcamel its interesting how my unit tests all passed then ...

Comment: Those are your attributes of comment model? then you have to change the name of comment attribute to something meaningful name.

Comment: Just because your unit tests passed doesn't mean it's a good idea. Please listen to Pavan, he knows what he's talking about.

Comment: @enragedcamel I did change it. Now to fix all my tests

Comment: alternatively you can permit all params see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Params**

```
params.require(:comment).permit(:author, :comment, :parent_id)
```

This will basically look for a hash which inherits from a `comment` key, like this:

```
{"comment" => 
   {
     "id" => "5", 
     "name" => "test" 
   }
}
```

So when you use the `require` method, you're basically saying "we need this top-level hash key", to which Rails will then go into the nested hash & use the `permit` method to locate the other attributes, as shown above.

The problem you have is this:

```
params => {"author"=>"157685iyutrewe1wq",
 "comment"=>"14253647turyerwe",
 "action"=>"create",
 "controller"=>"api/v1/comments",
 "post_id"=>"126"}
```

The problem here is you're calling `require` on the `comment` key; which is just a string. To fix this, you'll need to do something like this:

```
def comment_params
    params.permit(:author, :comment, :action)
end
```

--

**Save**

Something else you need to consider is the `controller_save` method. I've never seen this before, and is against convention. Not a problem with this, but means if you get team members on your app, or want to upgrade Rails, it will be a pain to adapt it.

I would definitely use the standard [`.save` method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/save), like this:

```
#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
def create
   ...
   @comment.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The Actual issue was that the attribute in the `Comment` model was also `comment`, upon changing it  (and the migration scripts as well as tests) to `comment_text` everything worked again :D

Answer (score -1):

Your 'params' are formed definitely not by a rails' form_for. Because it would be looked as `params: { comment: { "author"=>"157685iyutrewe1wq", "post_id" => "some_id" } }`

And so your params.require(:comment) returns 'String' object with value = "14253647turyerwe" and it really has no any 'permit' method.

So I suggest you to read about [forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) in rails, what html parameters they are construct while sending form data to a server

**UPDATE:**

If for some reason you have no mood for using a form_for @model helper, your whatever method of generating of form should produce for each field of that model something like this html:

```
<input id="comment_author" name="comment[author]" type="text" value="14253647turyerwe"/>
```

for them moment I suspect you got something like:

```
<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="14253647turyerwe"/>
```

Comment: No I stated in the comments to the post that this has nothing to do with forms. this is all done in react and the data is sent back through json. Good try though.

Comment: @user3379926 Why downvote me? It does not matter what your params formed: forms or JSON, I just pointed, to that your params variable is not formatted in Rails convention. And it still is. From wherever your controller get that data, make it look like { comment: { "author"=>"157685iyutrewe1wq", "post_id" => "some_id" } }